# 21 Game will not finish at 21

Tags: vb.net, game-engine

I am making a 21 game on Vb. The aim of the game is to make the user and the computer battle out. The computer generates a random number from  1 -3 and then outputs this. This then takes away from the total 21. The customer then does the same until the final number is 0. However this game doesn't stop at 0 and carries on going forever. Both the computer and the user should use the same 21 variable and I don't know how to get that to work either. So

1. Get the same variable to work for both the user and the computer
2. Make it stop at 21.

Here's my code:

```
Sub Main()

Console.WriteLine("In this game the aim is to be the last to get to  0 ")

Dim originalnum, playerturn As Integer

originalnum = 21

    While playerturn <= 21
        Randomize()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess from 1 to 3. Press enter after guess.")
        playerturn = Console.ReadLine()
        If playerturn > 3 Then
            Console.WriteLine("This is two high. Pick between 1 and 3.")
        End If
        originalnum = originalnum - playerturn
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is, {0}", originalnum)
        If playerturn >= 21 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You lost, the computer won")
        End If
        Dim random As New Random
        Dim computer As Integer
        computer = random.Next(0, 4)
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's go is, {0}", computer)
        originalnum = originalnum - computer
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's total is, {0}", originalnum)
        If computer >= 21 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The computer lost, You Won !")
        End If

    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like this? If I understand your question you are trying to present that the computer or the player won once someone is 0 or less. Correct.

```
Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine("In this game the aim is to be the last to get to  0 ")

    Dim originalnum, playerturn As Integer
    Dim PlayerNumber, ComputerNumber As Integer


    originalnum = 21

    While playerturn <= 21
        Randomize()
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess from 1 to 3. Press enter after guess.")
        playerturn = Console.ReadLine()
        If playerturn > 3 Then
            Console.WriteLine("This is two high. Pick between 1 and 3.")
        End If

        originalnum = originalnum - playerturn
        PlayerNumber = originalnum
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is, {0}", originalnum)

        If playerturn >= 21 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You lost, the computer won")
        End If
        Dim random As New Random
        Dim computer As Integer
        computer = random.Next(0, 4)
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's go is, {0}", computer)

        originalnum = originalnum - computer
        ComputerNumber = originalnum
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's total is, {0}", originalnum)

        If computer >= 21 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The computer lost, You Won !")
        End If

        If PlayerNumber <= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The computer lost, You Won !")
        End If

        If ComputerNumber <= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The computer Won, You Lost !")
        End If

    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: Basically the user can enter a number from 1 to 3. The aim of the game is to get from 21 to 0 the slowest. Whichever number the user picks, will be reduced from the original total 21 variable. Then the computer will randomly generate a number from 1 to 3 and take that off the same variable. The user and the computer will battle out to get to zero,using only numbers 1 to 3. On both of these codes they  don't go down at the same time. E.g if I choose 2 then the total should be 19 on both sides of the game (comp and user) They both need to reduce by the same ammount as they playing the same game

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are a bit conflicting. First you said the game should start at 21 and end at 0, but then you say that the game should stop at 21. I'm going under the assumption that it should start at 21 and end at 0.

You have a few problems in your logic. The game never ends because your condition on the loop is that the variable `playerturn` must be less than 21 to continue looping. The `playerturn` variable is used to hold the player's guess, which should always be between 1 and 3 (you are checking this but not forcing the player to re-enter their guess. I could enter 100, get the message that it's too high, and the game will continue on using my guess of 100).

You are subtracting the player's and the computer's guess from the `originalnum` variable, but never checking the value of it. I'm assuming that once this gets to 0, whoever got it there is the one who loses, right?

Something like the below should work. I modified the conditions that were checking `playerturn >= 21` and `computer >= 21` to check the `originalnumber` to be less than or equal to 0. I also modified the bit where you get and check the users guess...it will loop until a valid input is received.

Note that there are still some issues with your code, try turning `Option Strict On`. You also should test your player guess so that if they enter a letter or any character besides a number, it won't cause an exception.

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("In this game the aim is to be the last to get to  0 ")

    Dim originalnum As Integer = 21
    While originalnum > 0
        Dim playerturn As Integer = 0, computer As Integer = 0
        Randomize()

        'player input
        playerturn = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
        While playerturn <= 0 OrElse playerturn > 3
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your guess from 1 to 3. Press enter after guess.")
            playerturn = CInt(Console.ReadLine())
            If playerturn <= 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine("This is too low. Pick between 1 and 3.")
            ElseIf playerturn > 3 Then
                Console.WriteLine("This is too high. Pick between 1 and 3.")
            End If
        End While

        'check player answer
        originalnum = originalnum - playerturn
        Console.WriteLine("Your total is, {0}", originalnum)
        If originalnum <= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("You lost, the computer won")
            Exit While
        End If

        'computer input
        Dim random As New Random
        computer = random.Next(0, 4)
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's go is, {0}", computer)

        'check computer answer
        originalnum = originalnum - computer
        Console.WriteLine("The computer's total is, {0}", originalnum)
        If originalnum <= 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("The computer lost, You Won !")
        End If
    End While
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: `While playerturn <= 0 AndAlso playerturn > 3` - I think you meant `OrElse` rather than `AndAlso`, as there's no way `playerturn` can be <= 0 AND > 3 at the same time.

Comment: @RianBattle The user can enter a number from 1 to 3. The aim of the game is to get from 21 to 0 the slowest. Whichever number the user picks, will be reduced from the original total 21 variable. Then the computer will randomly generate a number from 1 to 3 and take that off the same variable. The user and the computer will battle out to get to zero,using only numbers 1 to 3. On both of these codes they don't go down at the same time. E.g if I choose 2 then the total should be 19 on both sides of the game (comp and user) They both need to reduce by the same amount as they playing the same game

Comment: @user5423489 This code should do exactly that. You were already using that variable to keep track of the total for both sides, since you were subtracting both the player's and the computer's guesses. You weren't, however, checking that same variable to be less than 0 as a win/lose condition (instead you were checking the guess variables to be >= 21, which shouldn't happen).